# Make A Control Be On Top

Tags: c#, image, windows-forms-designer, topmost

I have this one Image and I want it to be on top of another image.

(window form application, c#)

Comment: Is there a bring to front or bring to top method? Either in code or even a right click menu in the IDE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's one control partially overlapping another, and you want one or the other on top, right-click the image you want on top in the designer, and choose "Bring To Front". There is a "Send To Back" that you can use on the image you want behind the other.

If you want partial transparency, like an alpha mask on the top image or a gradient blend between two images right on top of the other, you'll probably need the more advanced capabilities of WPF graphics. You CAN do pixel-by-pixel effects in WinForms, but there isn't anything built in to Winforms to handle image transparency, and per-pixel manipulation of an Image in Winforms won't take advantage of any graphics acceleration (100% CPU, with the runtime's overhead slowing you down further).

Answer (score 13):

In the code you have a few of calls you can make. [BringToFront](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SendToBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.sendtoback(v=vs.110).aspx) are probably the simplest:

```
yourControl.BringToFront();
yourControl.SendToBack();
```

Also you could control that from the control's parent container using 
[Control.ControlCollection.SetChildIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). For example:

```
// Bring control to front    
MyForm.Controls.SetChildIndex(SomeControl, 0);
```

Otherwise just click "Bring to Front" or "Send to back" in the designer, as @KeithS has already answered.

Comment: Did not work for me, I ended up using someControl.BringToFront()